# How can I run my application when device is in locked state and screen is in turned off state?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I am using Alarm services to keep my application running when mobile is locked and screen turned off but it does not work.

My Alarm service class is:

```
public class AlarmService extends BroadcastReceiver {

  // Restart service every 60 seconds
  private static final long REPEAT_TIME = 1000 * 60;

  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    AlarmManager service = (AlarmManager) context
        .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent i = new Intent(context, StartUp_broadcast.class);
    PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i,
        PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    // Start 60 seconds after boot completed
    cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 60);
    //
    // Fetch every 60 seconds
    // InexactRepeating allows Android to optimize the energy consumption
    service.setRepeating   (AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
        cal.getTimeInMillis(), REPEAT_TIME, pending);

    // service.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(),
    // REPEAT_TIME, pending);

  }
}
```

and my brodcast service class is:

```
public class StartUp_broadcast extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, AlarmService.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.
                                     getService(context, 0, myIntent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context
                                .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                  System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000, 1000, pendingIntent);
    Intent Startup_Intent = new Intent(context, LocationService.class);
    Startup_Intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startService(Startup_Intent);
}

}
```

My main Activity class has PowerManager Service for WakeLock

```
 @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "MyWakeUp");
    wl.acquire(1000); //wake up the screen
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    this.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
    this.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
```

Kindly help me. How to keep my application running when mobile is locked and scrren is off ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run application when screen lock and also run alaram then you need to start service at boot. may be this link is helpfull to you.
http://www.androidcompetencycenter.com/2009/06/start-service-at-boot/

first read and do your self step by step. i hope it is helpfull to you.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine, only you need to change your Alarm variables to the class level with static modifier like below,

```
public class AlarmService extends BroadcastReceiver 
{
     private static Intent myIntent;
     private static AlarmManager service;
     private static PendingIntent pendingIntent;
     .
     . 
     .
}
```

Comment: When the phone is locked, for some HTC device, it is really impossible to unlock the device and take your app in the foreground. I tested in the HTC nexus and it was not working..But some samsung phones it was able to unlock the device.

Comment: Ok, I dont know about the unlocking, but for constant running Alarm my above code works excellent :)

Comment: @Lucifer: it only works for a minute and again it doesn't run application and not give updates:(   i want that application continuously works even it is locked, screen off etc.. please guide

Comment: @Lucifer: Yes friend, its not works when mobile is locked:( Thanks for help:) please help

Comment: @Mickel it will work for 70% of the mobile if you use the code i gave. For HTC phones, there is some issues. I have developed one app, uSleep where i am doing the same thing. Try it with my code instead of PowerManager.

Comment: **For HTC phones, there is some issues** , this is really new information for me, i will find some alternate for it

Comment: @Lucifer Yes dear. I tried in HTC Nexus one. But not working properly. You may figure it out..

Comment: @ArindamMukherjee , agree because Thread.sleep() also doesnt work on some phone. however i found alternate way for it.

Comment: I dont think that this answer deserve -1, so +1.

Comment: @Mickel I tried dude..But it was not working. Just check what are the devices it is not working for HTC..

Comment: @ArindamMukherjee: so friend, their is no solution at all for HTC:(

Comment: @Mickel I don't think, it will not work for all the HTC device. Some HTC device it will work for sure..just try it different devices..

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest you one thing..when your app will start and or the service will start, may be you can try to unlock the keyguard.

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);

getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
```

So when your app is running, it will unlock the key guard and keep the screen on. And when the service is stop, again lock the key guard.

**Note**: Don't use the PowerManager class. Because it will drain the battery very fast. I faced this problem.

Thanks.